# He dispels the darkness of ignorance from the lot of a nation

Tags: prepositions

I was reading a paragraph about a teacher:

> A teacher is an architect of a nation. He plays an important role in building up a nation. He dispels the darkness of ignorance **from** the lot of a nation."

My question is what it means by **"from the lot"**. To me, it would be all right if the sentence had **"from a nation"** instead of **"from the lot of a nation."** I have never read this type sentence before. Could you make an understandable explanation?

Comment: The sentence doesn't appear to be grammatical. Can you give us the quote in context so we can work out what the author means?

Answer (score 6):

I've found this sentence reproduced many times, so it appears it is not a misprint.

The "lot" of a nation means it's fate or destiny. For example "It is the *lot* of Canada to always be culturally influenced by its larger southern neighbour."

As I understand it the writer means that the nation has a "lot" which is the "darkness of ignorance", and the teacher is the one who dispels (removes) it from that nation's fate.

It's not a very good expression, at least in part because "lot" in this sense implies an unavoidable destiny, whereas the sentence means that the teacher is helping the nation to avoid the unavoidable destiny.

Comment: I think you may be right about what it was meant to say, but it's an awful expression.